# Why the interface is not displayed?

Tags: ios, swift

There are 2 functions:

```
func configure() {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 1200)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}
```

---

```
func configure1() {
    let listButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width - 30, y: 57, width: 25, height: 25))
    listButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    listButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "list.bullet"), for: .normal)
    scrollView.addSubview(listButton)
}
```

---

When calling these functions, only the scrollView is displayed, but the listButton is not displayed

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .gray
    configure()
    configure1()
}
```

---

If  combine the code of these functions into one, then everything works. Why doesn't it work out of two functions?

Comment: The `scrollView` you reference in `configure` is not the same one you reference in `configure1`

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `UIScrollView(frame: view.frame)`?

Comment: As already mentioned by @jnpdx `scrollView` goes out of scope when your first method finished. You probably have another scrollview declared as instance property of your view controller.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one question about your code, you created the ScrollView directly on Storyboard or directly on the code? If you created directly on code, the steps below should work.

I just paste your code to my Xcode and found some problems.

1. You did not paste the buttonAction code, so this error appeared:
   Cannot find 'buttonAction' in scope

To solve this, I did a simple function that prints in console "buttonPrint".

```
@objc func buttonAction() {
    print("buttonPrint")
}
```

2. configure1 function did not find scrollView in scope

To solve this, I created a `view controller instance property` declaring scrollView at the top of my ViewController, outside other functions, using the code below:

```
var scrollView = UIScrollView()
```

3. Redeclaration of scrollView

You declared scrollView on the first line of configure(). To solve the redeclaration, I simply deleted `let` statement.

Then I builded the app and it worked with these two functions :)

I'm using Xcode version 13.2.1 and an iPhone 11 simulator.

Comment: Não sei não ein, me pareceu que ele declarou a scrollView direto no código.

Comment: É, faz sentido mesmo. Inclusive vou incluir uma pergunta ali na minha resposta pra tentar entender melhor

Comment: obrigada @LeoDabus! É minha primeira vez respondendo perguntas aqui no stackoverflow

Comment: Bom saber! Vou anotar pra fazer nas próximas

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)